# Project Centennial: How to edit outputted XML and call MakeAppx.exe

Tags: powershell, uwp, desktop-bridge

I’m running into this error while trying to convert my Windows Forms Application using Project Centennial. I was able to run threw the shown VLC tutorial on the MSDN site, so I do know the converter is working. It says I need to “set the 'Application Executable' property in the AppxManifest.xml before calling makeappx manually” but I am not sure how to do that. I have tried using -AppExecutable but it’s not setting, every time it builds it defaults to MyApp.exe. It says I can edit it, but when I do not know how to call MakeAppx.exe with the same XML file.

Here is the command I am using:
     `.\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -ExpandedBaseImage      C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 –Installer C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Newest_Installer\Keyed-Setup.exe -InstallerArguments "/S"  -Destination C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Keyed_App_Filers -PackageName "Keyed" -Publisher "CN=JonesComm" -Version 1.0.2.2 -AppExecutable "KeyedApp.exe" -MakeAppx -Verbose`

Here is a picture of the full error.
[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKXTU.png)

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Last time I saw an error like this is was due to the project being converted to a different version of Net than I had on my computer (going backwards from 4.5 to 4.1).   I had to modify some of the xml and proj file and change  net version.  It looks like the error has to due with a license error, but i suspect it just wrong version of Net.  Check which version of Net is on computer and then open the xml and proj file in the project folder.

Comment: Project centennial forces you to target version .4.6.1 with your app, which i am and that is also what I have installed on my machine. The program has the 4.6.1 files downloadable as an offline prerequisite as well, something that the guidelines for setting up you project for conversion states. How where you able to modify the outputted .xml file and rerun the convertor without it recreating a new .xml?

Comment: Yes.  I had to set the Net version in the project to the correct version.  I downloaded a project from the web and wouldn't compile.  So I thought it wouldn't hurt to attempt to get it working with a little editing.  Sure enough it worked.  Not saying it will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!!! Okay so for about a week solid I have not been able to get this right. I have an MSI and a .exe of my program and I just successfully wrapped the .aapx with the MSI. The command that lead to the break though was “msiexec /?” this shows a list of the commands specifically for that application. “/PASSIVE” is the command needed to run without UI. I was able to set the 'Application Executable' property with “-AppExecutable "Executable(.exe) File Path"-AppInstallPath "Your Applications Installation Path” This is just the name of your applications executable, and where that executable would be located on a new computer after a fresh install.

Here is an editable version of the powershell command I used:

`.\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -ExpandedBaseImage C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 –Installer C:\Users \Desktop\MyApp\MyApp_Setup.msi -InstallerArguments "/PASSIVE" -Destination C:\Users\Desktop\MyApp-Appx -PackageName "MyApp" -Publisher "CN=Company" -Version 1.0.2.2 -AppExecutable "ApplicationFolder\SubFolder\MyApp.exe"-AppInstallPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\ApplicationFolder\SubFolder" -MakeAppx -Verbose`

I hope this helps any newbies out there like me. Project Centennial doesn’t have much for tutorials out there right now. Thanks everyone!!